Vite always building SSR for sveltekit static site regardless of setup
I cloned this site from a demo repo to try to get something to make sure that it's nothing with my setup.
So fresh clone - you can see from this output, that it's still building the SSR bundle even though the sveltekit is using the adapter static.
I get vite v5.0.12 building SSR bundle for production... ✓ 95 modules transformed. even though it shouldn't build anything via SSR.
    npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v5.0.12 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 95 modules transformed.
vite v5.0.12 building for production...
✓ 78 modules transformed.
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/version.json                                                        0.03 kB │ gzip:  0.05 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/.vite/manifest.json                                                      5.35 kB │ gzip:  0.78 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-greek-ext-400-normal.rKiNtwjr.woff2      7.51 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-cyrillic-400-normal.N-vuOVMo.woff2       9.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-greek-400-normal.At854Oju.woff2         10.52 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-latin-ext-400-normal.-l34kfv6.woff2     11.36 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-cyrillic-ext-400-normal.dOGCK5uJ.woff2  15.77 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-latin-400-normal.yoy1YEIp.woff2         16.28 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-all-400-normal.dpry7Ug7.woff            77.36 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/3.lLpc1E38.css                                     0.11 kB │ gzip:  0.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/2.8TujaP7J.css                                     1.39 kB │ gzip:  0.49 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/0.yMZRR6J4.css                                     4.96 kB │ gzip:  1.58 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/start.0gI5Rl0o.js                                   0.07 kB │ gzip:  0.08 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/stores.FCusXPiW.js                                 0.23 kB │ gzip:  0.17 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/index.ynOccO3Q.js                                  0.45 kB │ gzip:  0.32 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/nodes/1.eazWIcIr.js                                       0.84 kB │ gzip:  0.52 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/nodes/3.A_z3G-Va.js                                       1.11 kB │ gzip:  0.71 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/scheduler.YAOc3RFa.js                              2.16 kB │ gzip:  1.02 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/nodes/2.pLCzNBUr.js                                       5.08 kB │ gzip:  2.39 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/nodes/0.C3EXfSKJ.js                                       5.72 kB │ gzip:  2.56 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/index.ZrFKu9Ic.js                                  5.95 kB │ gzip:  2.51 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/app.9ZUkC_V2.js                                     6.25 kB │ gzip:  2.51 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/entry.CnUH1J8N.js                                 26.52 kB │ gzip: 10.51 kB
✓ built in 232ms
.svelte-kit/output/server/.vite/manifest.json                                                      4.45 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-greek-ext-400-normal.rKiNtwjr.woff2      7.51 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-cyrillic-400-normal.N-vuOVMo.woff2       9.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-greek-400-normal.At854Oju.woff2         10.52 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-latin-ext-400-normal.-l34kfv6.woff2     11.36 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-cyrillic-ext-400-normal.dOGCK5uJ.woff2  15.77 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-latin-400-normal.yoy1YEIp.woff2         16.28 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/fira-mono-all-400-normal.dpry7Ug7.woff            77.36 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_page.lLpc1E38.css                                 0.11 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_page.8TujaP7J.css                                 1.39 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_layout.eM0QSbz7.css                               5.21 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.js                                                 0.07 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/internal.js                                                              0.31 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/fallbacks/error.svelte.js                                        0.47 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/stores.js                                                         0.80 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/about/_page.svelte.js                                      1.07 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index.js                                                          1.33 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js                                                            3.59 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js                                          5.76 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/exports.js                                                        5.96 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js                                                       5.96 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_page.svelte.js                                            7.67 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js                                                                92.01 kB

Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-static
  Wrote site to "build"
  ✔ done
✓ built in 724ms

My config files are :
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
    }
};

export default config;


My vite.config.js file is :
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
};

export default config;

From the docs and as far as my knowledge goes, this should work i've kept it as plain and basic as possible. But I always get the SSR build output when running vite build.
Any help or guidance or suggestions.

These are intermediary files, they will not be part of the final build output. Why do you care about this?
